# How to query uniswap unclaimed fees with api? (powershell/curl)

Tags: uniswap, exchange-api

I am trying to query the unclaimed fees from an uniswap pool with a script. I am using powershell, but a simple curl request can easily be translated.

There are 2 similar questions on stackexchange, but the answers don't solve my problem unfortunately:

[UniSwap V3 API : How to track **unclaimed fees** programmatically?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/99906/uniswap-v3-api-how-to-track-unclaimed-fees-programmatically)

- the top answer explains how to make requests to Infura, but I don't see these eth_call requests in my dev tools, nor any requests to infura.
- the second answer is actually the best option I have until now. It uses the openbank api. The only issue with that, is that you can't specify an individual pool id. You have to specify a wallet address and then you'll get info of ALL pools linked to that wallet. The problem is that you don't have a unique id to make sure you are looking at the right pool (an issue when an owner has multiple similar pools with similar amounts of money in them).

[Trying to make sense of Uniswap v3 fees (feeGrowthInside0LastX128, feeGrowthGlobal0X128)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/101955/trying-to-make-sense-of-uniswap-v3-fees-feegrowthinside0lastx128-feegrowthglob)

- this uses the "TheGraph" api, but the calculations mentioned in the answers don't even get close to the results shown on Uniswap itself.

Code snippet:

```
$UrlTheGraph = "https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/uniswap/uniswap-v3"   
$thegraphBody = @'
{
    "query": 
        "{ position(id: $pool_id ) { owner { id } liquidity token0 { symbol decimals } token1 { symbol decimals } transaction { id } depositedToken0 depositedToken1 withdrawnToken0 withdrawnToken1 collectedFeesToken0 collectedFeesToken1 feeGrowthInside0LastX128 feeGrowthInside1LastX128 pool { liquidity feeGrowthGlobal0X128 feeGrowthGlobal1X128 } tickLower { feeGrowthOutside0X128 feeGrowthOutside1X128 } tickUpper { feeGrowthOutside0X128 feeGrowthOutside1X128 } } }",
    "variables":
        null
}
'@

function Get-PositionInfo {
    param (
        $pool_id
    )
    $body = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($thegraphBody)
    $temp = Invoke-RestMethod -Body $body -Uri $UrlTheGraph -Method Post
    $temp.data.position
}

$temp= Get-PositionInfo -pool_id 148048

[bigint]$feetoken0 = ([bigint]($temp.pool.feeGrowthGlobal0X128 - $temp.tickLower.feeGrowthOutside0X128 - $temp.tickUpper.feeGrowthOutside0X128 - $temp.feeGrowthInside0LastX128) / [bigint]([math]::Pow(2, 128)) * [bigint]$temp.liquidity / (1 * [math]::Pow(10, $temp.token0.decimals)))
[bigint]$feetoken1 = ([bigint]($temp.pool.feeGrowthGlobal1X128 - $temp.tickLower.feeGrowthOutside1X128 - $temp.tickUpper.feeGrowthOutside1X128 - $temp.feeGrowthInside1LastX128) / [bigint]([math]::Pow(2, 128)) * [bigint]$temp.liquidity / (1 * [math]::Pow(10, $temp.token1.decimals)))
$feetoken0
$feetoken1
```

(the BigInt's where necessary as the numbers got too big)

The pool in the code example currently has 18.55$ in unclaimed fees, made of 7.94 USDC and 0.002503 ETH. With my script, I get 2 times 0 back in this case. I tried different pools (other currencies, higher numbers too), but the results are never close to what the Uniswap interface shows.